# FirstOrDefault throws ArgumentnullException

Tags: linq, argumentnullexception

My goal is to extract a specific record that has a parameter value specified by me. The data is taken from an external API.

My query looks like this:

```
var productId = productsResponse.Where(x => x.Parameters.Any(y => y.Values.Any(z => z.Equals(auctionTitle)))).FirstOrDefault();
```

And it works fine until where filters out all the records. Then the method aborts and debugging cannot continue.

The problem is:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

because source transferred to `FirstOrDefault` is null.

I also tried:

```
var productId = productsResponse.Where(x => x.Parameters.Any(y => y.Values.Any(z => z.Equals(auctionTitle)))).DefaultIfEmpty().First();
```

Please let me know what topic I should read because I have run out of ideas. I really care to understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Troom, welcome to SO. Can you re-check your code if it is the exact same code that you shared here is throwing the exception, or you have something like `var productId = productsResponse.Where(...).FirstOrDefault().ProductId` ??

Answer (score 0):

This can be not an answer but try this construction:

```cs
var productId = productsResponse
   .Where(x => x.Parameters.SelectMany(y => y.Values)
      .Any(z => z == auctionTitle))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also if data came from external API, it may be needed more null check.

```
var productId = productsResponse
   .Where(x => x.Parameters?.SelectMany(y => y.Values ?? Enumerable.Empty<Value>())
      ?.Any(z => z == auctionTitle) == true)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I ran out of knowledge about null checking from an external API. I have to read about it, you helped me a lot.